# R networkD3 sankey - change the colors for all links to blue

Tags: javascript, r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

Here is example code that I use to make a Sankey chart using `networkD3::sankeyNetwork()`

```
library("networkD3")

a <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = "
date,Data Center,Customer,companyID,source,target,value 
")

node_names <- unique(c(as.character(a$source), as.character(a$target)))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(a$source, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(a$target, node_names) - 1,
                    value = a$value)

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              sinksRight = FALSE)
```

I want to change the color for all links to blue. I think the argument 'linkgroups' might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to your `links` data.frame that will specify the group for each link (in your case, they will all be in the same group). Then add a custom color scale command that will specify "blue" for that group. Then tell the `sankeyNetwork()` function the name of the column in your `links` data.frame that specifies the link group and pass it you custom `colorScale`.

```r
library("networkD3")

data <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = "
date,Data Center,Customer,companyID,source,target,value 
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,open_list_view_1,open_card_2,1 
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,open_card_2,edit_card_3,1
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,edit_card_3,save_card_4,1 
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,save_card_4,back_to_card_list_5,2 
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,back_to_card_list_5,show_more_6,1
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,show_more_6,view_introduction_7,1
6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,view_introduction_7,scroll_down_8,2
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,open_list_view_1,open_card_2,3
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,open_card_2,edit_card_3,1
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,edit_card_3,save_card_4,4
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,save_card_4,back_to_card_list_5,2 
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,back_to_card_list_5,show_more_6,1
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,show_more_6,view_introduction_7,1
6/2/2021,dcA,customer2,companyID2,view_introduction_7,scroll_down_8,5
")

node_names <- unique(c(as.character(data$source), as.character(data$target)))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(data$source, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(data$target, node_names) - 1,
                    value = data$value)

links$linkgroup <- "linkgrp"

colourScale <- 
  'd3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(["linkgrp"])
     .range(["blue"].concat(d3.schemeCategory20))'

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              sinksRight = FALSE, 
              LinkGroup = "linkgroup", 
              colourScale = colourScale)
```

[image]